# Image request failing. Possible HTTPS issue

Tags: perl, http

I'm working with some Perl code that I don't understand:

```
my $tmpdir = "XXX";

my $src = "tmp" . time . int rand 10 . ".jpg";

while ( -s "$tmpdir/$src" ) {
    $src = "tmp" . time . int rand 10 . ".jpg";
}

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( keep_alive => 0, timeout => 10 );

my $req = HTTP::Request->new(
    "GET",
    "https://www.com/act/couponimage/1877",
);

my $res = $ua->request( $req, "$tmpdir/$src" );

if ( ! $res || ! -s "$tmpdir/$src" ) {
    header( 301, 0, 0, "https://www.com/" );
    exit 0;
}
```

For some reason it hits the point where it redirects to the main page (the header code).

There is clearly something wrong here because it never executes past the last `if` clause which redirects. Maybe it has to do with using HTTPS?

It is not a filesystem issue. The following coupon image path works fine

Xxx.com/img/coupon-2600.jpg

Comment: Make sure `LWP::Protocol::https` is up-to-date and you are using a recent version of `OpenSSL`. Include versions of `IO::Socket::SSL`, `Net::SSLeay`, `LWP`, and `LWP::Protocol::https` in your question. Also, don't live link to questionable sites unless you want to be flagged for spamming SO.

Comment: Have you tried `$ua->request($req)` without the file parameter? Do you get the response you expected? That should help you debug the problem

Comment: @SzG: It's always nice to see a readable question, but it's *essential* that any edits you make exactly maintain the OP's intent and the syntax of their code. It was very wrong of you to remove multiple parentheses from [the OP's third edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45043109/3) without being utterly assured that you had not altered the way the code would behave in their environment. White space is the safest and most useful tool to improve code, but even then you must be careful not to change the contents of a literal string or invalidate any line numbers in the body of the question

Comment: I removed my answer since what it says fits here -- your code works for me (tested with 5.10 and 5.16).  Comments: (1) the `while` trick is too elaborate, better use `File::Temp` if you want a new file with a  random name.  (2) Make sure that you _can_ write the `$src` file at that location.

Answer (score 0):

The request should be working fine,
but as pointed out, you really should check what version of the packages you are using.
For me ( perl 5.22 - LWP::UserAgent 6.26 ) the call `$ua->req( $req )` needs to be `$ua->request( $req->uri )`. And the file to store the response in must be given with `$ua->request( $req->uri, :content_file => $fn )` .

I think the original author assumed the content file would be created by giving the filename to `$ua->request`. With `:content_file`, that is what's happening for me. He put the while ( -s $src ) in place to ensure he got a filename that was not yet taken.

Thus, I believe the solution to your problem is to change

`my $res = $ua->request($req, "$tmpdir/$src")` to

`$ua->request($req->uri, ':content_file' => "$tmpdir/$src" );`

The docs mention that using :content_file means the actual response content is no longer stored in the object, so you may have to adapt your code.
If all you need is the file, I would adapt the final if to check for the file that should now exist ( which should, I believe, only happen upon successful response ).

If what you need is the $res object to use later, I would probably opt to check the response worked, then print the content to the file you want it in, so just do

`my $res = $ua->request( $req->uri );`

adapt the if accordingly and print content to file.
I would personally prefer the latter, as I can check the response for success, then print: this seems much clearer.